# how can I split up a line based on a string

Tags: bash, variables

If I have the following string:

```
variable_A=12345variable_B=54321variable_C=24680
```

how can I split it up based on the content of the string, so for instance if I wanted to extract everything after "variable_B" the result would be

```
variable_B=54321variable_C=24680
```

the "delimiter/string" would be included in the final result0

this being in a bash environment. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
$ echo 'variable_A=12345variable_B=54321variable_C=24680' |
    grep -o "variable_B.*"
```

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ echo 'variable_A=12345variable_B=54321variable_C=24680' |
    sed -r 's@.*(variable_B.*)@\1@'
```

The output are :

```
variable_B=54321variable_C=24680
```

Answer (score 2):

So you just want to remove everything in front of the delimiter, but keep all other variables in your final output?

Another pure bash approach removes up to and including the delimiter and adds the delimiter back in front:

```
$ foo="variable_A=12345variable_B=54321variable_C=24680"
$ foo="variable_B${foo#*variable_B}"
$ echo "${foo}"
variable_B=54321variable_C=24680
```

Comment: thanks! had gone with sputnick's solution although this seems like a great alternative as well

Comment: @lacrosse1991 For such a simple string manipulation this is actually the preferred solution (unless you are stuck with a shell that does not support it) as it doesn't spawn a separate process (each command in a pipe is executed in a subshell). The code is more compact as well.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, have been working on optimizing the script that I needed this for, will have to try switching over to this method instead :)